# Flatten Array using Jolt Transformation

Tags: json, jolt

This is input JSON which has array, which can contain one or more objects.
inside the object lang is array. It will always have one object which is fix. I want to flatten it.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "James",
    "id": 1,
    "lang": [
      {
        "primary": "python",
        "secondary": "c++"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Kevin",
    "id": 2,
    "lang": [
      {
        "primary": "scala",
        "secondary": "java"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to flatten the JSON like this - expected output

```json
[
  {
    "name": "James",
    "id": 1,
    "primary": "python",
    "secondary": "c++"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kevin",
    "id": 2,
    "primary": "scala",
    "secondary": "java"
  }
]
```

Im tryin to build specification like this but its not working

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": "[&1].name",
        "id": "[&1].id",
        "lang": {
          "*": {
            "primary": "lang\\[&2\\]\\.primary",
            "secondary": "lang\\[&2\\]\\.secondary"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No need to escape for the square bracket characters
- Increment from `[&2]` to `[&3]` as the value on the right hand
  side(in order to traverse the colon following the innermost `"*"` )
- Try to think symbolically(no need to repeat the literals, but use
  ampersands to replicate them)

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&", // the rest of the attributes(other than "lang" array)
        "lang": {
          "*": {
            "*": "[&3].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much, can you please share some resources where I can learn when touse &1 &2 &.

Comment: Barbaros - Can you please explain why you have used &3

Comment: You are welcome @shobhit . You can check out [the source of the library](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases), and some blogs such as [this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Jolt-quick-reference-for-Nifi-Jolt-Processors/ta-p/244350) .

Comment: Since you need to reach the level where `lang` array stays. In order to reach that you need to traverse two objects(count `{` signs), and a colon just after the innermost `"*"` as you need a representation for the RHS(right hand side). If you need to qualify for the LHS, then going two level up (`&2`) would suffice. @shobhit